# Just show folders with preg match php

Tags: php, preg-match, match

i am looking for a way to just show folders in php.

i am getting files like this returned from my amazon foreach loop using undesigneds s3 class.

Computer Fix Files/files/driver-ml-dlan-usb-windows-r2.exe

here my foreach.

```
foreach ($contents as $file){

    $folder = rtrim($file['name'], "/");

    if (!preg_match("/[0-9\.\-\_]/i", $folder)) { ?>

                <?php echo $folder; ?>

                <?php } 

    }
```

ok this kinda works but what i really want to do is just list the first folder.

so instead of this.

```
Computer Fix Files/files/
```

it would just show.

```
Computer Fix Files
```

any help please????

Answer (score 2):

```
echo substr($folder, 0, strpos($folder, '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo reset(explode('/', $folder));
```

should work.